# job interview question -data structures 

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, include

Suppose I have set of files and in every files there are include# to other files in the same set.Suppose I have function that load all the includes in certain file.I need to write function that load all the includes in some given source file so I will avoid infinite loop and circular call for the include.

To solve the question I have to use this function i can't use pragma once or something similar
I think it could be solved by recursion though I am not sure how

Thank you

Comment: What does "load all the includes" mean? Do you mean you need to write a preprocessor that handles #include directives? Maybe give an example of what you expect your function to do (what its input and output is). And what does this have to do with databases?

Comment: i have a functiom that performs include of all header files included in my file - and this is the only functuion I can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to look at [Topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Answer (score 4):

Define a preprocessor variable, typically 'CLASSNAME_H'

Check to see if the variable is defined and, if not, then define it and execute the code.  For example:

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include "Other.h"

class User { };

#endif
```

This is what you're talking about, right?

Comment: Commonly called "include guard".

Comment: What about using `#if !defined(USER_H)`?

Answer (score 3):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, **#pragma once** is a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive designed to cause the current source file to be included only once in a single compilation.

Comment: i know....it just has to by implementation not using pragma once and similar

Comment: @Yakov: Please state all constraints in the question.

Comment: You've formatted your answer as a quotation. Can you please include a citation?

Comment: @Rob: Looks like it was from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

Comment: It was exactly from that place, sorry. I quoted the phrase but end up forgetting add the reference. Shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems you can't use the normal check for include guards or `#pragma once`s. Another way is to save the absolute (or maybe relative) path for every file you include in a string and if you encounter on of the include pathes again, don't include the file.